# Is there a Phonegap function that is called when the application becomes active?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need a Phonegap function similar to the following function in objective-c:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Everytime the user starts the app or goes back in, the function should get called. Is there something similar in Phonegap or another way of implementing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html you can use `deviceReady` for first load and `resume` for anytime after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are pause and resume events, documented with examples in the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.pause.html).

Example code for your device ready handler function:

```
document.addEventListener('pause', onDevicePause, false);
document.addEventListener('resume', onDeviceResume, false);
```

Then implement suitable callbacks to run your logic for each event.